# How do I run PHP scripts via CMD without typing "php"?

Tags: command-line, php

If I have a batch file called "program.bat"... and I'm on the command line... I can just type `program` to get the program to run.

If I'm on the command line, how do I get `program.php` to run automatically the same way instead of having to enter `php program.php`?

Say I have PHP installed to `C:\programs\PHP` and `C:\Programs\Scripts` attached to `PATH`. What needs to be done to be able to create `C:\Programs\Scripts\hw.php` with the content

```
<?php Echo "Hello World!"; ?>
```

and have it so that on the command line I type `hw`?

Windows XP Pro, SP2
[PHP 5.3.8](http://windows.php.net/download/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file association for .php. See the documentation for `assoc` and `ftype` That should get you to where typing `program.php` causes php.exe to be invoked and passed program.php.

To eliminate the need to type the '.php' suffix I suspect you need to tell Windows that .php is an executable extension. See [On Windows, what filename extensions denote an executable?](https://superuser.com/questions/228680/on-windows-what-filename-extensions-denote-an-executable/228693#228693) re the PATHEXT environment variable. I have not tried this myself.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php Assoc and FType got me searching for the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a `hw.bat`, and put `php hw.php` in it?  Then you can just run "hw".

Comment: I'm trying to be lazy... last thing I want to have to do is setup two scripts for each task I want to do. Works? Yeah... but definitely not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Type "assoc .php=PHP_program_file" at the command prompt.
Also add .PHP; to the beginning of the environmental variable PATHEXT which is at System in the Control Panel, Advanced, Environmental Variables.
Also add something like "C:\php;" to the beginning of the environmental variable PATH so you can also type "php hw.php" in addition to "hw.php" or "hw".

Then do the following in the registry editor:

Enter C:\php\php.exe "%1" %*
in HKEY_CLASS_ROOT : PHP_program_file : shell : Execute PHP Program : command
(Each colon means place a registry key inside the first registry key. Screenshot included.)

[Registry editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9goVS.jpg)