# How can I open .PHP files with PHP.exe in Windows 7?

Tags: php, windows

I have WAMP (Apache/MySQL/PHP) installed on Windows 7. PHP 5.3 is included.
I tried "test.php -> right-click -> open with -> browse -> PHP.exe" but PHP.exe does not get added to the "Open With" list. However, it does work if I use "path\to\php\PHP.exe -f "path\file.php".

What should I do?

Comment: Not a programming question, but windows-specific.

Comment: So what exactly is the question? "How can I add `php.exe` to the Open With list"?

Comment: Related: [How do I run PHP scripts via CMD without typing “php”?](http://superuser.com/questions/347583/how-do-i-runphp-scripts-via-cmd-without-typing-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put PHP in your path, for one.

1. Right click on "Computer" and select Properties
2. Select the "Advanced" tab
3. Click on the "Environment Variables" button
4. Select Path and click "Edit"
5. Add this to the path, making sure to add semicolons as separators:

   C:\path\to\php

You should also edit your apache httpd.conf file, to add support for .php files:

```
# 
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

More info can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php